# How to customise firebase DocumentData interface?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firebase@5.5.8 and typescript@3.1.4

whenever I create a document from firestore i get an object of type `firebase.firestore.DocumentReference` as expected

If I call the `get(options?: firebase.firestore.GetOptions|undefined)` I'll get a object of type `firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot` as expected

If i call `data(options?: firebase.firestore.DataOptions|undefined)` I'll get either a firebase.firestore.DocumentData object or undefined, as expected

Now, on my manager object, I know what I'm writing to the databse, so I can make the assertion that whatever DocumentData you get out of my manager, you'll get a Client as shown

```
export interface Client {
    name: string;
    website?: string;
    description?: string;
    visible: boolean;
}
```

I want to create an interface for my manager object that expresses that. So I've tried:

```
export interface FirebaseDocumentSnapshot<T> extends $firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot {
    data(options?: $firebase.firestore.SnapshotOptions | undefined): T|undefined
}

export interface FirebaseDocumentReference<T> extends $firebase.firestore.DocumentReference {
    get(options?: $firebase.firestore.GetOptions | undefined): Promise<FirebaseDocumentSnapshot<T>>
}
```

The problem i've got is here:

```
const client: Client = mapClient(args);

const result: FirebaseDocumentReference<Client> = await $db.add(client);
```

the error is:

[ts]

```
Type 'DocumentReference' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseDocumentReference<Client>'.
  Types of property 'get' are incompatible.
    Type '(options?: GetOptions | undefined) => Promise<DocumentSnapshot>' is not assignable to type '(options?: GetOptions | undefined) => Promise<FirebaseDocumentSnapshot<Client>>'.
      Type 'Promise<DocumentSnapshot>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<FirebaseDocumentSnapshot<Client>>'.
        Type 'DocumentSnapshot' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseDocumentSnapshot<Client>'.
          Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
            Type '(options?: SnapshotOptions | undefined) => DocumentData | undefined' is not assignable to type '(options?: SnapshotOptions | undefined) => Client | undefined'.
              Type 'DocumentData | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Client | undefined'.
                Type 'DocumentData' is not assignable to type 'Client'.
                  Property 'name' is missing in type 'DocumentData'. [2322]
const result: FirebaseDocumentReference<Client>
```

How can i declare the interfaces so I can know the type of the resulting object?

Comment: Why don't you just cast the object returned by data()?  For example: `const client = snapshot.data() as Client`?

Comment: because I want to return the DocumentReference and have access to all the firebase goodies rather than returning the raw data object

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you need a special generic typed DocumentReference.

Comment: Well. I have a manager service that controls my application's access to firebase, specially when creating new records, and what I want from that manager service i s to return me a DocumentReference of whichever entity it created. and with TypeScript I want to be able to know what type of data I'll get once i get that documet reference's data. Besides, what good is DocumentData?. Why DocumentSnapshot.get() returns just any|undefined? or just any for that matter

Comment: Without seeing your entire system, it's really hard to understand why this is more helpful than just casting to an interface.  Your code is going to have to make an assumption about what's in that document, and a cast is as good as any way to make that assumption.

Comment: @Simon have you managed to find a solution? I'm also interested in this to reduce casting boilerplate in my code.

Comment: @ramon_salla I did, but by inverting logic and switching to an ActiveRecord pattern

Answer (score 37):

A simple solution would be to **cast the return data:**

`const client = snapshot.data() as Client`

Answer (score 15):

@gal-bracha's solution will "work" in the sense that the TypeScript compiler will assume `client` is of type `Client`, but it doesn't prevent a runtime error if bad data ended up in Firestore. A safer solution when dealing with any data external to your app is to use something like [Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) to validate data explicitly:

```js
import * as yup from "yup";

const clientSchema = yup.object({
  name: yup.string(),
  website: yup.string().url().notRequired(),
  description: yup.string().notRequired(),
  visible: yup.boolean()
});
// You can use this elsewhere in your app
export type Client = yup.InferType<typeof clientSchema>;

// Usage
const client = await clientSchema.validate(snapshot.data());
```

This is more defensive as `clientSchema.validate` will throw an error if, for some reason, bad data ended up in Firestore. After `validate()`, you're guaranteed, that `client` is a `Client` and not just telling the TypeScript compiler "treat this as a `Client` even though at runtime, it may not be".

Answer (score -1):

```
export declare function getDocs<T>(query: Query<T>): Promise<QuerySnapshot<T>>;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for your code.